# Textview is not appearing in 3.1

Tags: android, textview

I have a simple Layout file. What's happening basically is that empty `TextView` is not appearing(without setting its `Text` property).
This issue is encountered only in version `3.0,3.1` and `3.2` OS.
Empty `TextView` is not occupying its space or in other  words empty textview is not visible.

Empty textview is visible after setting following properties.

1. android:focusable="false"
2. android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
3. android:clickable="true"
4. android:inputType="text"

What can I do to make it visible? Please respond ASAP.

Comment: Empty text view cannot be visible, it is there but it cannot be visible unless you set a background or some text to it which is in contrast to the background.

Comment: @Chronically Insane- that i know when empty textview has a same background color it will not display. But this is happened only in 3.0 to 3.2 OS versions. It left its space from layout.

Comment: Please post your code and if there is any error on the logCatty!

Comment: there is no need to post code. To examine that just make one demo project with 3.1 api. And just place one textview and remove its text on layout. You can see my problem also in Graphical layout by selecting android os version 3.1. When os version is 3.1 then u will not see empty textview on layout.

Comment: actually what kind of demo you want to show? you are telling the xml code which generated is got gone ? if you wont set the text ?

Comment: @Rohan what you mean by `it left its space from layout`? seem question need more info to understand your issue quickly.

Comment: "there is no need to post code" -- yes, there is. "To examine that just make one demo project with 3.1 api" -- your job is to make it easy for people to help you. Supplying sample code, particularly a full project, that demonstrates the error is one way to do that. Supplying screenshots indicating the difference in behavior is another way to do that.

Comment: add background color and check if it is there or completely invisible. maybe it is a matter of theme or something.. Add a red background and check

Comment: Question is not that much explanatory or i can say i couldn't understand what actually your requirement is. If you post the code of your layout it will be helpful to answer or fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need it to keep row height in layout.
The simplest solution, I think, would be to set whitespace as a text for all TextViews in xml.

```
 android:text=" "
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set the visibility property **explicitly**?:

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

> The visible property can be:
>
> - "visible" = showing
> - "invisible" = not showing yet still taking space in the layout
> - "gone" = not showing and not taking space in the layout.